# Getting started on database design

Tags: database, denormalized

I'm just getting started to try creating my first database, and I'm stuck.

I have multiple customers who buy every month (m-m relationships). I have multiple suppliers who sell every month (m-m relationships). Every customer can buy from multiple suppliers, and every supplier can sell to multiple customers (m-m relationships).

How I connect them all together?

Comment: Made some English corrections. Added tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of what Customer bought from what Supplier, try having a joining table:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerPurchases
(
    id int not null identity(1,1)
    ,customerID INT NOT NULL
    ,supplierID INT NOT NULL
    --make customerID a foreign key of Customers and supplierID a foreign key of supplier
)
```

Now, every time a customer buys something, insert a record into the joining table.  From there, you can get any Customer's purchases based on the customerID column or anything the supplier sold, based on the supplierID.  If you wanted to go further, add an "ItemsPurchased" column to the joining table.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kalmino's answer, but a little more specific.

Typically in this use case, you would also have an `Orders` table, in addition to your customers, suppliers, etc, instead of linking a `customer` directly to a `supplier`. It might look something like this:

```
        CREATE TABLE Orders
        (
            id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
            CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
            SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
            OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
            OrderQuantity INT NOT NULL,
            ProductID INT NOT NULL
        ), 
-- example of a foreign key definition, do this for Customers also
    CONSTRAINT FK_SupplierID_Suppliers FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
    REFERENCES Suppliers (id)
```

or maybe in a master-detail form:

```
 CREATE TABLE OrderHeader
    (
        OrderID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
        CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
        OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
        ShipDate DATE NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE OrderDetail
    (
        OrderID INT NOT NULL,
        OrderQuantity INT NOT NULL,
        ProductID INT NOT NULL,
        SupplierID INT NOT NULL
    )
-- FK definitions and stuff
```

Add columns for cost, etc. as needed. Now you can query for orders that were placed by a given user, filled by a given supplier, by date, etc. Basically, when you find yourself needing to track extra things that don't yet exist, you need to think about not only the relationships, but what "objects" or "entities"  those things represent, and define them in a table.